# Where it better to save the temp data getting from web-service and using in activities?

Tags: android

I am using asynchtasks for getting data from rest-ws and I am using these data in some activities.I see 2 main ways:
 - save these temp data in activities
 - save these temp data in my singletone application controller class(not mvc controller)
 -(I cannot already after getting use these data's)

But I feel that these 2 ways not very good ideas.
How can I solve this problem better?

Comment: How much data are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to save web-data is to create content provider, fetch data in thread/service/asyncTask and insert it into content provider. Notify your activities, and activities should fetch the data from content provider. look at the following google guide lines [Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)

Answer (score 1):

to save your data in your application is relative to many reasons like how much data are we talking about , and the type of data ...etc

take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) , it is explained very well all types of data storage.